# writing text over image and move that text using javascript with asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, flash

I want an image editor or a way (javascript code) I can write text over image and I can move that text within image area.

My project is in ASP.NET.

I want something like this.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/imageeditor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

and at last I want to save that image with text.

Thanks

Comment: try to use html5 canvas with pixastic jquery library

Comment: thanks for your answer but do you have any link with example?